# Does the undo button let you keep gold generated by gold income items?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does the undo button let you keep gold generated by gold income items?

For Example:

1. I die
2. While dead, I buy gold income item (for example Avarice blade)
3. after I spawn I undo purchase

Will I keep the gold generated by gold income items or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gold that you gain from GP10 items will be **Removed** upon klicking the undo button. The patch notes of the patch in which the feature was  added state that:

```
Items will remove benefits they granted you when undone, such as gold gained from gold over time items.
```

Apart from that all gold you gain in the game is permanent.

Note that you also cannot undo boot enchantments.

Comment: Is there anywhere that states why you can't undo enchantments? Aside from homeguard I can't imagine any abusable features?

Comment: @Shelby115 I think especially homeguard would be the problem. You could just buy it and then click undo to just get thr MS buff. Maybe they didn't want to program a buff removal for the undo button.